# How can i get sql query Equivalent to a linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

How can i find out when my program execute a linq expression what sql query has been executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiling is a sure way. Depending on the LINQ provider, this may also be inbuilt, for example with LINQ-to-SQL you can assign anything to `.Log` and it will write the queries as it does them. At the simplest level:

```
dataContext.Log = Console.Out; // for a LINQ-to-SQL DataContext
// TODO: now execute some queries against dataContext
```

Internally, we use a custom ADO.NET stack for this (and some other things). It *looks* like a `SqlConnection` (and LINQ-to-SQL is perfectly happy with it), but it does some logging and profiling for us on every command executed, so we can see where our long running operations are. I think Sam is looking to make this available to the public if you want.

Comment: I am using ef ? And i can't find log property. can u guide me?

Comment: @LightWing - EF is not LINQ-to-SQL, so there is no .Log property. However, I suspect our ADO.NET hook would work OK. I've checked, and we do indeed plan on making this available shortly, but it won't have been tested against EF, simply because we don't use EF. You might also consider using Ayende's tool: http://efprof.com/

Answer (score 1):

Profiling the database would do it.  Keep in mind that the statement won't be executed against the database until your code goes to interrogate the results of the query.

Comment: And If i haven't access to database?

Comment: This solution requires your having access to the database.

Comment: Are there any another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?

I believe it shows a SQL prototype of your query.

Comment: Yes i have linqpad and linqer.

Comment: @LightWing - And, after you put your LINQ query in it, have you looked in SQL tab below?

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use SQL Profiler, comes with
   SQL server install, and capture the
   statements as they execute
2. you can use tool like LINQPad and
   run the LINQ against your data store
   and examine the SQL within the tool
3. you can debug your application and
   get the SQL from the
   `ObjectQuery.ToTraceString` method

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = somequery;
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: I'm currently looking for the book I read this from. But meanwhile, yes I think so, since it was used in Console.WriteLine